# Nearest unique duplicate points

Tags: qgis-processing, nearest-neighbor, duplication, unique-value

How can I highlight nearest(certain distance) unique duplicates? Actually I tried a process in ArcGIS but only duplicates are pulled out from the entire file without considering distance. How can I do the process in QGIS.

[image]
[image].

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376622/find-nearest-point-with-the-same-attribute ?

Comment: I think it will help me to sort out my issue. could you please let me know where I have to use this code I mean in expression or any other area. Thanks....