# QGIS expression with overlay_nearest and filter condition: problem with first feature

Tags: qgis, expression, qgis-expression

There seems to be a strange behaviour using QGIS expressions `overlay_nearest()` function with filter condition. The problem can be reduced to this [minimal reproducible example](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/WMZqkjswRurmzyR) (Geopackage with random point layer; see the comment to [this answer for the larger context](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/461863/88814)):

[image]

The idea is the find all features with the same `name`, using `overlay_nearest()`. To get the values in the attribute field `result`, I used this expression:

```
array_to_string(
    with_variable (
        'nname',
        name,
    eval('
        overlay_nearest(
            @layer,
            name,
            limit:=11,
            filter:=name='''  || @nname  || ''')
    '))
)
```

It returns all features with the same name, including the current feature - so for `id`=4, it returns three times `D` as we have 3 feature with that value: 4, 5 and 7. This is the expected behaviour.

However, in the case of features with `id`= 0 or 1, it returns just one result. Playing around with the expression, it becomes clear that feature with id=0 only finds feature with id=1 and the other way round. So the first feature seems to be treated differently.

Why is that respectively: how to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, I [reported it accordingly](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/53494).

A workaround mentioned there is to duplicate the layer and use this duplicated layer in the `overlay_nearest()` function as the bug seems to be limted to the case when refering to the very same layer.